# How to create a site with menus and categories that collapse and bold for each page and category?

Tags: html, css, menu, categories

This might be a basic question but I've been searching the web for an hour, including stackoverflow. I've created my layout and I have the menu on the left with 3 main categories. I want to create a site in which these categories link to pages for that category with subcategories underneath the parent category on the menu on the left.

I'm using HTML and CSS in Dreamweaver and the final site will be listing and showing products using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Keep searching.. there are a lot of examples on the internet.. After you code something come here and ask for help if needed

Comment: Just in a fast search: http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html, http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/slidedown-menu2/slidedown-menu2.html#, http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: I have seen all those sites and a lot of examples, for example there is one page that lists 100 examples, but they are for menus that have items that open new menus on the same page. I'm looking for one that shows it like that on the page you click to, with the category bolded depending on which page you are on.

Answer (score 2):

you can write all the code on your own, which is very good to learn how to develop web-applications. In that case you might want to take a look to the jQuery website and use a jQuery plugin which can be useful in your case, like [menuTree](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/menuTree). See the example:

http://menutree.pixelhandler.com/jQuery-MenuTree-Plugin/example/

But I think that if you want to deploy a professional web-site you should use a CMS like Drupal, Joomla or even Wordpress; with these tools you can accomplish your task very easily.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use such plugins. I also don't have time for a new thing like jQuery as I need this site done in about 30 hours.

Comment: I've figured out how to do it actually. Just by luck a lightbulb went off in my head. Now I just need to figure out how to get the products listed from the database and sorted according to the links in the main div.

Comment: @user1780775, jQuery is hardly a "new" thing.   It's the best ajax solution for dynamic cross-browser sites.  If you don't have time to learn anything that will help you and you can't use any plugins... how do you expect to do this?   IMHO, thirty hours does not seem realistic.

Comment: I meant new as in new to me. I expect to do it with PHP and MySQL.